# How to perform submit button function in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

I am new to coldfusion ,
please check my code below

```
<cfif isDefined("form.submit")> 
 <cfoutput> 
     <h3>hi</h3> 
 </cfoutput> 
</cfif> 
<cfform action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#"> 
  User Name:<cfinput type="Text" name="usr_nm"><br> 
  <cfinput type="Radio" name="access_flg" value="0">Admin
  <cfinput type="Radio" name="access_flg" value="1">User</br>
  <cfinput type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br> 
</cfform>
```

But ,When I am clicking submit button ,I am expecting result as **hi**

I haven't see hi message, Is there any thing wrong in my code ,Any one please help me

Comment: I just ran this exact code on my own page (CF11) and it executed as you expected. Logic-wise this code is perfectly valid as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the replay..,My requirement is like this... when end user click submit button i want to get details from textbox and radio button ,then insert into database ,I don't want to redirect another page,How can I do this ..could you please help me

Comment: Try adding method="post" to your CFFORM tag. In older versions of CF, it defaulted to "get," which'd cause the behavior you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,I am  trying to execute my code in online http://trycf.com/  ,I haven't see hi

Comment: Did you follow Joe's suggestion?  By the way, not related to your question, but `<cfif structkeyexists(form, 'submit')>` has advantages over `<cfif isDefined("form.submit")> `.

Comment: yes..i added metod=post..but no luck.

Comment: @Soujanya do you have anything inside an htaccess or web.config that re-writes URLs?

Comment: *execute my code in online trycf.com*  .. which could explain it. Not everything will work *exactly* the same as if you were running the code locally. Keep in mind those pages are dynamic, so a self-posting form may not work the same way (or at all).

Comment: You do not gain anything from using `cfform` in this case. Use a plain old `form` and `input` elements and, as Joe noted, add `method="post"`. And...run the code in a local version of ColdFusion, not on trycf.com.

Comment: I second what @ScottStroz says. There's no reason to use `<cfform>` here (or, in general: ever). Just use a `<form>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're new to ColdFusion, I'll give you some advice straight away:

**1. Do not submit a form to the same page.**

Submit the form to a separate page for processing. Reason being, as you get into more advanced applications, you'll need to restrict pages/URLs to only respond to an appropriate HTML Verb.

Your form page should respond to HTTP GET.
Your form processing page should only respond to HTTP POST.

**2. Do not use CFFORM.**

The function of `CFFORM` is to create JavaScript validation and server-side interactions. This can easily be done with modern JavaScript libraries like

- https://jquery.com/
- http://jqueryvalidation.org/

**3. Give your form elements an `ID`, as well as a `NAME`.**

This allows easier reference to the form elements when using JavaScript.

**4. Do not name your submit button "submit".**

If you ever want to use JavaScript to submit a form, the function is `submit()`.

For example: `$('#myForm').submit();`

Having a form element named the same as a function will cause errors.

Here's `my_form.cfm`:
`<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="my_form_action.cfm" method="post">
    User Name:<input type="Text" id="usr_nm" name="usr_nm"><br> 
    <input type="Radio" id="access_flg_0" name="access_flg" value="0">Admin
    <input type="Radio" id="access_flg_1" name="access_flg" value="1">User</br>
    <input type="submit" id="my_form_submit" name="my_form_submit" value="Submit"><br> 
</form>`

**5. You don't need to use `CFOUTPUT` unless you are rendering data from the server.**

Here's `my_form_action.cfm`:
`<cfif structKeyExists(form, "my_form_submit")> 
<h3>Hi!<lt>
</cfif>`

Even better:
`<cfif (cgi.request_method IS "post") AND (structKeyExists(form, "my_form_submit"))> 
<h3>Hi!<lt>
</cfif>`

Comment: All good tips. @Soujanya - Putting aside best practices for a moment, there is nothing *technically* wrong with the code. A self posting form simply won't work on that site, due to the way the dynamically generated scripts are handled. Online tools are a great convenience, but .. they (understandably) have some limitations. What you experienced is one of them.  I recommend trying one of the CF express versions (both Adobe and Lucee have one). Just download and click a .bat file and you are ready to run .cfm scripts on your local machine (and try out the tips above :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions , I followed  "Adrian J. Moreno " ,That is working fine.After completed my operation in action class.I want to come back to the original page(means HTML) page,How can I do this ,could you give me some suggestions

Comment: @Soujanya the easiest thing to do is to use `CFLOCATION` to redirect from the processing page to whichever page you want to go next.

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration of this part of Adrian's answer:

```
<cfif (cgi.request_method IS "post") AND (structKeyExists   form, "my_form_submit"))> 
<h3>Hi!</h3>
</cfif>
```

This is a candidate for code re-use.  In one of our applications, I wrote a custom tag that does something like this:

```
if (StructKeyExists(attributes, 'ScopeToCheck') is false)
attributes.ScopeToCheck = "form";

if (StructKeyExists(caller, attributes.ScopeToCheck) is false) 
Redirect = true;
else if (StructIsEmpty(caller[attributes.ScopeToCheck]) is true)
Redirect = true;
else
Redirect = false;
if (Redirect == true)
location(somewhere, false);
```

The custom tag approach was appropriate for my situation.  For other situations, the same logic can be put into a udf that returns either true or false.  Then the calling page can decide what to do with that information.